# Include file content in the variable

Tags: php

In my applications I often use AJAX calls to get certain variables along with html code, sampe JSON:

```
{
    'result': '1',
    'error': '0',
    'someVar': 'abc',
    'outputHTML':   '<table>....</table>',
}
```

to create such JSON I have to assign each value in the associative array and encode it (server side: PHP code).

```
$response=array(
    'result'    =>  1,
    'error' =>  0,
    'someVar'   =>  'abc',
    'outputHTML'    =>  '<table>....</table>',
);
echo @json_encode($response);
die();
```

I have my HTML code directly inside my classes, but I would like to move it into a separate template file to reduce class size and separate class code from html code. The problem is that I'm unable to get template code into a variable, sample:

```
function ajax_response()
{
    $response=array();
    //of course below code doesn't work
    $response['outputHTML']=include('table-html.php');
    echo @json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

where table-html.php file includes:

```
<table>
    ...
</table>
```

One solution to the problem is to use output buffering to catch the content of table-html.php file and insert it into the variable. The downside is that the output buffering isn't always enabled on servers, so on some hostings such code wouldn't work correctly.
Do you have any suggestions on alternative solutions to the problem ?

Note: Template files use PHP code to generate dynamically the HTML code, so the included PHP file must be parsed.

UPDATE

In fact this code will work:

```
$response['outputHTML']=include('table-html.php');
```

if the table-html.php has the following content:

```
<?php
$output = '<table>'.$some_var.'</table>';
return $output;
```

Comment: This is what happens when you skip language basics and try to solve problems in a pedantic way. Include & require load photo file for interpretation

Comment: Oh wow, missed that completely. My apologies!

Comment: @Yoshi not a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`include` and `require` are used to load PHP code into your application.

To get the content of a file and store it in a variable use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead.
Do note that given path to the file is relative to the entry script. This might give unexpected results when your script is included from somewhere else. To counter this, use the `__DIR__` magic constant.

Final code would look like:

```
$response['outputHTML'] = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/table-html.php');
```

### If you want to parse PHP however

First of all, you might want to look at a templating engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), and save yourself some trouble.

If you want to do it yourself, the only thing you need to change in your code is to return a variable at the end of `table-html.php`. I'd suggest using [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to create readable and easy templating.

**Example**

```
<?php
    return <<<EOT
        <table>
            <tr><td>$firstname</td><td>$lastname</td></tr>
        </table>
    EOT;
```

Comment: I thought about using file_get_contents() function but it doesn't parse PHP code. It would work fine for HTML code, but when I use PHP code then this function won't work.

Comment: Ah, it was not clear from your question you wanted to execute PHP inside the `table-html.php` file. I'll add a fix for that to my answer.

Comment: Though a bed idea but hereyou go http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: At the end of my question there's a notification that I want to parse PHP code.

Comment: NO, eval is not evil, it just requires some cautiousness